# Is the velocity a scalar or a vector in one dimensional Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, lorentz-symmetry, relative-motion

Is the sign of velocity v important in the one dimensional Lorentz transformations?

My question arises because the length contraction and the time dilation effects will work out in exactly the same way independent of the direction of motion of the moving body.

Comment: This question seems utterly unrelated to its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign has no effect on the factors.  The direction only matters to length contraction because lengths are contracted in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

The sign/direction of the relative velocity between the two frames matters when transforming coordinates, velocities, momenta, energies, forces, etc.

The length contraction and time dilation factor $\gamma$ depends only on $v^2$ so the sign/direction of $\vec v$ doesn’t matter for them.

The relative velocity between the frames is really a vector, but often Lorentz transformations are written so that the relative motion is the $x$-direction, making the vector-ness of $\vec v$ less obvious.